# spring & plsql stored procedure - exception handling & transactions

Tags: hibernate, spring, plsql

I need to call oracle stored procedure from spring (via Hibernate).

I'm not familiar with PL/SQL so I would like to know how to proceed with that.

1) Can I use spring/hibernate (for instance annotations) to begin/close transaction. I assume that it's not an issue and I don't have to begin/close inside stored procedure.

2) In the mentioned procedure I'm opening and closing the cursor but in case of exception I would like to close it and rethrow an exception to Java part, so here's what I've done:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   CLOSE my_cursor; 
   RAISE e_cannot_do_sth;
```

I want to raise an exception so I could let user know that something went wrong...

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can use Spring do manage the transactions. I don't think Hibernate will give you much of an edge here.
2. To throw an exception, use the following:

   `raise_application_error(errno, 'Error Message of your choice');`

Where `errno` is a number between -20000 and -20999. Then in your Java code, catch the org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException, pull out the root SQLExcection as follows:

```
private SQLException digOutSqlException(UncategorizedSQLException t) {
  Throwable root = t;
  while (root.getCause() instanceof SQLException) {
    return (SQLException)root.getCause();
  }
  return null;
}
```

And call `getErrorCode()` on the SQLException to get your custom error PL/SQL error number.